# Office js - different icon for each taskpane

Tags: excel, office-js, manifest, office-addins, excel-addins

I am working on an office.js add-in that has more than one task pane.
Each task pane has a different icon in the ribbon. but when I open more than one task pane I can see the same icon in the panel to the right (the Icon of the entire addin as defined in the `IconUrl` tag in the manifest file).

In the image you can see 2 identical red icons - this is the main problem,

My Question:
Is there a way to define a different icon for each task pane?

[image: you can see the same icon appears twice in the right panel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way currently. I'd suggest posting a feature request for that.

Feature requests on `Tech Community` are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Thanks, I've added the request: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-taskpane-icons-titles-that-are-different-than-the-addin/idi-p/3194628#M738